# I can't access the server with backuppc from the local network

Tags: networking, server, permissions, apache2, backuppc

If I go to http://127.0.0.1/backuppc/ or http://localhost/backuppc/, everything is fine.
If I try to go to http://10.x.x.18/backuppc/ or [http://domain.my/backuppc/,то](http://domain.my/backuppc/,%D1%82%D0%BE) I get

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.
Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) Server at domain.my Port 80

And also from any PC on the local network

If I try to go to http://10.x.x.18/ or [http://domain.my/,то](http://domain.my/,%D1%82%D0%BE) I get the standard Apache page:
Apache2 Default Page
It works!
This is the default welcome page used to test the correct operation of the Apache2 server after installation on Ubuntu systems.

And also from any PC on the local network

Comment: What is the actual question? What are you trying to do?

Comment: From my PC to control backuppc on the server backups. In error.log apache "client denied by server configuration"

Comment: You may want to reword the title and some of the question. 127 is the local network. So it is not clear what you are doing.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Could you [edit] your question to include: (1) how you installed/configured `backuppc` (2) the Apache `.conf` file for the enabled site(s). With this, it may be possible to better understand what is preventing you from accessing the path.